# jQuery Transition only works on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

First of all, I'm totally new to jQuery (I'm more a desktop app developer)

I'm trying to build my first jQuery code, which consists of a "sliding" transition effect between 3 DIV.

I can't figure out why it only works on Chrome, and not on FF or IE.
Neither the first one nor the second one wants to move or to hide.

Any help on this one will be greatly appreciated, thanks by advance !

here is my current code :

jQuery :

```
$(function () {

    var contentWidth = '-' + ($('.content').width() + 1000) + 'px';

    $('.content').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: contentWidth
    });    

    $('#ligne1')
        .animate({ left: 100 },"fast")
        .addClass('visible');

    $("a.temp").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $blockID = $( $(this).attr('href') );
        if ($blockID.hasClass('visible')) { return; }
        $('.content.visible')
            .removeClass('visible')
            .animate( { left: $(window).width() }, function () {
                $(this).css('left', contentWidth);
            });
        $blockID
            .addClass('visible')
            .animate({ left: 100 }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Here is my CSS :

```
.wrapper { position: relative;}
.content { width: 900px; height: 300px; padding: 0; left: 0; top: 0; }
.box { width: 900px; height: 300px; }
#ligne1 .box { background: green; }
#ligne2 .box { background: yellow; }
#ligne3 .box { background: red; }
```

And finally here is my HTML :

```
<a class="temp" href="#ligne1">One</a>
<a class="temp" href="#ligne2">Two</a>
<a class="temp" href="#ligne3">Three</a>
<div class="wrapper" style="style="position: absolute; left: 50%; ">
    <div id="ligne1" class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="ligne2" class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="ligne3" class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a jsfiddle for it

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the firefox error console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the event object into your click handler:

```
$("a.temp").click(function (event) {...}
```

This is the error from the Firebug console in FF:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: awesome! thanks cfs. it looks i still have a long road to learn :)

Comment: @Pascamel: Look into getting firebug. It'll help you with debugging in Firefox.